# Loop nested array in twig

Tags: twig

Im trying to loop through this (for me) quite complex array with Twig. I want to be able to print out all elements. How would you do that? Below is the array and the code im currently trying.

This is the array: https://pastebin.com/TZSANFpW

I have tried this so far but it gives me error: "Notice: Array to string conversion in "

```
            {% for route in routes %}

            <p>
                {{ route.admin }}
            </p>

        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read out a full array, you would to create some form of recursion.
You could achieve this with a macro in the line of

*macros.twig*

```
{% macro readArray(array) %}
    {% import _self as macros %}
    {% if not array is iterable %}
        {{ array }}
    {% else %}
        {% for k,v in array %}
        <ul>
            <li>
            {{ k }}: {{ macros.readArray(v) }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

*main.twig*

```
{% import "macros.twig" as macros %}

{{ macros.readArray(results) }}
```

[example](https://twigfiddle.com/ueoztb)