# Passing an array to macros in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, macros, twig, symfony4

I am trying to use twig macros to create re-usable snippets on html code that I insert back into my main template however I'm running into an issue when attempting to pass an array to my macro:

Macro call:

```
{{ wrapper.outputConclusionList(viewData['response']['Report']['ContactBullets']) }}
```

Macro function:

```
{% macro outputConclusionList(list) %}
    {% for listItem in list %}
        {% if loop.index == 0 %}
            <div>
                <b>{{ listItem|raw }}</b>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div>{{ listItem|raw }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Symfony Error log:

> [2018-06-04 11:31:19] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")."

I've tried searching for anyone who might have run into this issue before but can't seem to find anything, does anyone know if it should be possible to do this (the twig documentation doesn't seem to suggest it isn't possible)?

Alternatively, is there a different approach I should be taking with this?

Comment: Seems that you are passing a multi dimensional array towards `twig`, hence the notice. This mean u would need to do some check first before trying to output the correct values. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579143/loop-nested-array-in-twig/50581938#50581938)

Comment: Ah yes, following up on this I found the listItem value was in fact an array. The error pointed to the call of the macro so I assumed something was wrong with the variable I passed rather than what I was doing within the macro, thanks for the help

Comment: Yes `twig` can't determine the correct line of error when calling a macro for some reason :)